# INTL show "dash" on undefined/empty values

Tags: javascript, intl

Is there a way to define a number formatting with INTL in a way that it will format empty values as "-"? I know how intl deals with formatting values, but what about the absence of a value? I want a format expression/style, so I need to avoid using Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts(), as I am using a framework that only allows me to specify an intl format

thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you can simply check the value before passing it to a formatting function. Something like `return value ? formatToNumber(value) : '-';`. But without more details I can't think of what exactly you are after. Can you specify which libraries you are using if any? And maybe provide an example of what you are trying to achieve.